# Wednesday's Mirror Donimoes Problem

Tags: sliding-blocks, dominoes

Help four ghosts find each other in a haunted house. I just finished adding a
new puzzle to [Donimoes](https://donkirkby.github.io/donimoes/), my collection of domino puzzles and games, so I
thought I would post a few bonus problems here. The puzzle is Mirror Donimoes,
and the ghosts are four pawns that walk around on top of the dominoes, trying to
find each other. Each domino is a room in the house, and the ghosts can't go
through the closed doors. They can go through the mirrors, though. Spooky!

See [Monday's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/99304/38) problem for complete rules and and an example solution.

Today's problem is a little bigger and a little more challenging. Good luck, and post your solution as an answer.

[image: Wednesday problem]

If you like this puzzle, watch for a more challenging problem on Friday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picture of (updated, legal) solution

EDIT: It has been brought to my attention that I did math wrong :) The last two steps have 28 moves and 30 moves, respectively.

> [image: A solution in 31 moves]

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution. Did you swap left and right? Also, remember that the dominoes have to stay in one connected group.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remember that rule! I will adjust the solution as soon as I have time.

Comment: Very nice! I think you miscounted the moves in your second-to-last picture, though. I count your total moves as only 29. Good luck with the Friday finale that I just posted!